# Estimate location, scale and shape parameters of skew normal distribution with the method of maximum likelihood in python

Tags: python

I want to fit a skew normal distribution (SN) in a set of data. In order to do that, the location, scale and shape parameters of the SN have to be estimated.

These parameters can also be computed analytically but I'm looking for an estimation method.

So far I have estimated the parameters by using the sum of least squares method but I also want to do it by using the maximum likelihood method.

In the first part of the code, a custom skew normal distribution is build
with known location, scale and shape parameters just to get started:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import special
from scipy import optimize
from scipy import stats

# PDF of a standard normal distrinbution:
def pdf(x):
    return 1 / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * np.exp(-x ** 2 / 2)  

# CDF of a standard normal distrinbution:
def cdf(x):
    return (1 + special.erf(x / np.sqrt(2))) / 2         

# PDF of skew normal distribution:
def skew(x, e, w, a):
    t = (x - e) / w
    return 2 / w * pdf(t) * cdf(a * t)                   

# build a custom skew normal distribution:
n = 2**10
e = 1.0    # location
w = 2.0    # scale
a = 4.0    # shape

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, n)
y = skew(x, e, w, a)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Now lets assume that the data where the SN model has to be fitted is:

```
e = 5.0    # location
w = 1.5    # scale
a = 3.0    # shape

data = skew(x, e, w, a) + stats.norm.rvs(0, 0.04, size=n)  # real data

# real data is a set of noisy data following the SN distribution
# with e=5.0, w=1.5, a=3.0

plt.plot(x, data)
plt.show()
```

Assuming that the e, w and a are unknown, an estimation method allows us to find them from the "real" data.

With the method of sum of least squares:

```
def opt(parameters, x):
    return skew(x, parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2]) - data

initial_estimates = np.array([1., 1., 1.])

parameters_est = optimize.leastsq(opt, initial_estimates, (x,))

print(parameters_est)

# printed: (array([ 4.9984384 ,  1.49246143,  3.03745207]), 1) 

model1 = skew(
              x, 
              parameters_est[0][0], 
              parameters_est[0][1], 
              parameters_est[0][2]
              )

plt.plot(x, data)
plt.plot(x, model1)
plt.show()
```

So the method of least squares works and provides estimates of e, w and a close to the actual values.

Now I'm trying the estimation method of maximum likelihood. In code:

```
def log_lik(params):

    location = params[0]
    scale = params[1]
    shape = params[2]

    # PDF of a normal distrinbution:
    phi = (1 / (scale * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))) * np.exp((-(y-location)**2) \  
          /(2 * scale ** 2))

    # CDF of a normal distrinbution:
    PHI = 0.5 * (1 + special.erf(shape * (y - location) \ 
          /(scale * np.sqrt(2))))

    # the PDF of SN is 2*phi*PHI

    # log-likelihood function for SN:
    L = n * np.log(2) - n * np.log(scale) + np.sum(np.log(phi)) \ 
        + np.sum(np.log(PHI)) 

    return L

y = data

initial_estimates = np.array([1., 1., 1.])

MLE = optimize.minimize(
                        log_lik, initial_estimates, method='nelder-mead'
                        )

print(MLE.x)

# printed: [ 1.7  0.1  1.3]
```

So, it seems that I cant make it work. My question is simply what is wrong and how to estimate the e, w and a using maximum likelihood method.

Comment: Well for one, you have weird line breaks in your code, can you fix that?

Comment: ok. I edited the post, hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, people use centered parameterization (CP) instead of direct parameterization (DP) for optimization purpose in the univariate skew normal case. If using DP, like what you are doing right now, your initial value needs to be chosen more smartly and the estimation is very dependent on your initial values. I would suggest you start with several different starting values (well separated) and compare the LogL value.

BTW, did you minimize the log likelihood? It should be 'maximize'.